# Codex 1r available with historic remarks?

Tags: greek, manuscript

Does anyone know, if Codex 1r (used by Erasmus) is available for online reading? How about history of the manuscript, what do we know about it? I'm especially interested of the Revelation part of it written in minuscule Greek.

**Update:**

I found manuscript is renumbered as 2814 nowadays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuscule_2814

However, wiki page doesn't mention much of the history and origin of the manuscript itself. Could it be from times of Andreas Caesarea? At least commentary of Andreas is found from the copy which Erasmus was using:

> “Cursive no. 1, of the 12th or 13th century containing the Apocalypse, with the commentary of Andreas, is of particular interest, since it was the only Greek Ms. which Erasmus had for the Apocalypse in his first edition of the Greek Testament (1516)“

Isbon Beckwith. Apocalypse of John, p. 412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work you are looking for appears to be available online [here](https://archive.org/stream/handschriftlich00deligoog#page/n8/mode/2up).  It is included in the work, *Handschriftliche Funde: Die Erasmischen Entstellungen des Textes der Apokalypse* , by Franz Delitzsch, which is linked by the Wikipedia entry you provide.  There are notes in English beginning on page 91.  The Greek text begins on page 36, interspersed with German commentary by Dr. Delitzsch.

By the way, Andrew's commentary has been translated into English by Dr. Eugenia Constantinou in her 530-page Ph.D. theses available [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjb29iQysDTAhWJwlQKHWK0BWgQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.preteristarchive.com%2FBooks%2Fpdf%2F2008_constantinou_andrew-translation.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGlV3YOfqC0aKRh2A-LEhmRWi3A4g&sig2=vBXD3CIrOohK3HQ4ujhH3Q).  According to Dr. Constantinou, Andrew's commentary was included in many manuscripts of Revelation and factored into the book being included in the New Testament canon.